# HTML/CSS div not aligning at top of page

Tags: css, html, alignment

Sorry for what seems like a repetitive question but none of them have solved my issue.

All the margin, border, and padding settings are set to 0px. The margin-left and margin-right of the main page div are set to 15px on either side. At least I can't see anywhere I have forgotten to set one of those to 0px.

For some reason, the top div of the page will not align at the top of the page.

If I put any text between the `<body>` tag and the `<div class="main">` tag, that will be hard up against the top of the screen, but any text within the div "main" tag or the div "header" tag will have a margin of about 15px from the top of the screen.

header.php:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
<?php header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8'); ?>
<title><?php echo $title; ?></title>
<link href='css/main.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />
</head>

<body>

<div class='main'>
    <div class="header">

        <img src="images/header1.png" id="header" />
    </div>
    
    <p class='heading_1'>Welcome to D T Hourn Photography</p>
    <p class='bodycontent'>
        Introduction blob
    </p>
    <p class='bodycontent'>
        Albums:
    </p>
```

css.main:

```
html
{
border:0px;
padding:0px;
margin:0px;
}

body
{
font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-style: normal;
background-image: url('../images/bg1.png');
background-attachment:fixed;
padding:0px;
margin:0px;
border:0px;
}

.main
{
top:0px;
margin-top:0px;
margin-right:15px;
margin-left:15px;
margin-bottom:0px;
border-top:0xp;
border-left: 2px outset #445566;
border-right: 2px outset #445566;
width:93%;
max-width:1400px;
background: rgb(222, 222, 222);
background-color:rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6);
}   


.header
{
    border-bottom: 2px groove red;  
    margin:0px;
    background-image:url('../images/header1.png');
    background-size:100% 100%;
    height:200px;
}


img#header
{
    width:100%;
    height:200px;
    vertical-align: bottom;
    border:0px;
    padding:0px;
    margin:0px;
    
}

.heading_1 
{
    font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    height:1.5em;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #000000;
}

.heading_2
{
    font-weight: bold;
}

table
{
    border:1px solid #0000ff;
    padding:0px;
    border-collapse:collapse;
    background-color:#ffffff;
    
}
.tables_heading 
{
    font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 1em;
    font-weight: bold;
    background-color: #99ccff;
    border-bottom:1px solid #0000ff;
}
```

EDIT: added extra code from the header.php file. as said if I put plain text between `<body>` and `<div class="main">` then that text is hard against the top of the browser. but anything between the div's has a border of ~15 pixels.

The actual site (what I've done so far) can be seen at http://dthourn.com/photography

The live version renders as I want it in firefox (at least on my computer) but not on I.E or google chrome. it doesn't render as I want it in any browser on my local computer.

Comment: It looks like you have missed out some html, all that is there is the head, and we can't tell much from that.

Comment: Can you provide the part of you HTML with the elements using `.header` and `.main`? The given part is rather not helpful. -- I guess it's just your header pushing the main content downwards.

Comment: The `<?php header` command doesn't work in that position, but I don't think that causes the problem.

Comment: correct border-top:0xp; on '.main'

Answer (score 15):

Add simply this one to your css file:

```
body { margin:0px; }
```

Hope this will solve your problem.

Answer (score 2):

Just use...

```
*{margin: 0; padding: 0; border: 0; outline: 0;}
```

Comment: border is only really applicable if you add a border on yourself. and margin should be margin: 0 auto; to centre everything.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
.main
{
top:0px!important;
margin-top:0px!important;
margin-right:15px!important;
margin-left:15px!important;
margin-bottom:0px!important;
border-top:0xp!important;
border-left: 2px outset #445566!important;
border-right: 2px outset #445566!important;
width:93%!important;
max-width:1400px!important;
background: rgb(222, 222, 222)!important;
background-color:rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6)!important;
}
```

Comment: That is not good practice to use the `!important`tag whereever you need it. This should be used in few cases, which don't allow another or simple enough solution. Better cleanup the CSS properly. This is not the issue though, because of the missing `position` attribute the `top` value will not have any effect.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following to the top of your css file:

```
html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre, a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code, del, dfn, em, font, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp, small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var, b, u, i, center, dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li, fieldset, form, label, legend, table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td { margin: 0; padding: 0; border: 0; outline: 0; }
```

Then further down make sure to give the various elements within your divs padding again, for instance:

```
p { font-size: 12px; padding: 12px; }
```

I usually give the padding the same value as font-size but the nice thing about this approach is that you can customize it as you please.

Comment: I don't think it is a good solution to leave this css in your project, but you can use it to find the real reason for your problem by removing parts of the line until your problem reappears.

Answer (score 0):

I've been working on this prob for hours. I copied and pasted thequerist's answer and finally it worked. No more space at the top. I've reset everything that I could have thought to 0px but I obviously missed one.

Answer (score 0):

For people new to HTML, some tags (like `<p>` and `<h1>`) add padding so they don't go all the way to the top of the page. I like to use `<span>` when I run into this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Thought i would chuck my two cents in here: Just an extract of your css, alot of unneeded code here, so took it out and shortened it:

```
.main
{
margin: 0 auto;
border-left: 2px outset #445566;
border-right: 2px outset #445566;
width:93%;
max-width:1400px;
background: rgb(222, 222, 222);
background-color:rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6);
}
```

In terms of `<p>` and `<h1>` tags, you just need to manually set the margin & padding off whenever you use these. 
A little tip if your doing this in a browser and text editor, on the browser press F12 and it should bring up a developer/debugging console. On their you will be able to see what is using your margins etc and should help you out.

Answer (score 0):

If margin: 0px; is not enough you can always use negative margin like this:

```
.example {margin-top: -10px;}
```